# Implodes remove double quotes

Tags: php, implode

```
$view_array = implode(',', $view_array);
```

When I var_dump this the value is "3,1" how can I remove the outer quotes so it will become 3,1 only

Comment: you cant, its a string after using implode, technically it's not part of the data.

Comment: is there any way so that I can convert it to int ?

Comment: can `1,2,3,4` be an int, is it an int.  it's not.  The quotes don't really exist it's part of `var_export`, do `echo` instead...

Comment: Why you need to remove these `"` from the string??

Comment: @FrayneKonok I tried but it is not working

Comment: A string always is in the single `"`, You can't remove it, but if you have only numbers then you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

The quotes are part of the way you are outputting it.  They don't exist, there is no spoon.  Use `echo` instead...

```
   $view_array = [1,2,3];
   $view_array = implode(',', $view_array);
   echo $view_array;
```

Outputs

```
  1,2,3
```

Comment: Very funny, What a magical solution. Great. I think this is what the OP looking for and by mistake try with `var_dump()`.

Comment: well it's like wondering how to remove `string(5)` from `var_dump` `string(5) '1,2,3'`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `explode`, and just use the value by itself:

```
$view_array = explode(',', $view_array);
echo $view_array[0];
```

Or put it in a loop and render them all

```
$view_array = explode(',', $view_array);
for ($i=0; $i < count($view_array) ; $i++) { 
        # code...
        echo $view_array[$i];
    }
```

Comment: `echo $view_array[0]` is incorrect `implode` creates strings not arrays,  this would just echo the first character of the string from implode.

Comment: Ah totally, fixed now. Thanks loads mate!